# How to include GitHub issues & PRs in API-triggered repo import into GitLab?

Tags: github, gitlab, backup, remote-backup, github-organizations

Many academic organizations are present as such on GitHub, but may also have a self-hosted GitLab CE instance.

In order to automatically and fully backup the former onto the latter, they may want to run some kind of script that triggers their GitLab to import all repos from their GitHub org. This is possible through the GUI with the [`github_importer`](https://gitlab.com/import/github/new) ([docu](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/github_importer.html)). It's not feasible manually and continuously for many repos.

Using GitLab's [`Create project`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#create-project) and [`Import file`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/project_import_export.html#import-a-file) APIs, I puzzled together this (Bash) code which creates GitLab projects from the given GitHub repos:

`curl --request POST
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $API_SCOPE" \
    --form "namespace_id=$GROUP_ID" \
    --form "path=$REPO" \
    --form "import_url=https://github.com/$ORG/$REPO \
https://git.domain.edu/api/v4/projects/`

*`ORG` would be the source organization on GitHub and `GROUP_ID` a dedicated `GitHub-archive` group on the GitLab CE instance.*

However, this only imports files & Git history, not GitHub issues, PRs, labels, etc. but those are desired for a full backup. So, I wonder:

1. Is there a 3rd API endpoint relevant to this task? `/projects/import` seems to *require* a `file` attribute, but trying to read the file list from GitHub first, would probably exhaust the API limit too quickly for a a feasible backup solution.
2. Is there another  `--form ""` flag one can add to the `/projects` requests that makes it behave like the `github_importer`?
3. Does the latter maybe have an undocumented API?
4. Does one need to use [`gitlab-rake import:github[…]`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/raketasks/github_import.html#doc-nav)?

Thanks for any hints to the above questions, or pointers to existing solutions/tools/scripts, regardless of language. Thank you!

*PS: Yes, the above script would be overkill compared to [GitLab's built-in `Repository mirroring`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/repository_mirroring.html), but that doesn't include issues, PRs & labels either.*

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2018, `4.` seems to be the only answer. Once [GitLab's own "Import repositories API endpoint" issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/18726) gets implemented, it may become an option for `1.`.